# Difference between Javabean and Java Beans

Tags: java, terminology

I'm confused. I've seen two different terms: `Javabean` and `Java Beans`. Is there a significant difference between them?

Comment: Where did you see these terms?

Comment: I saw those in searching in google or in book. I'm wrong?

Comment: It is nice that I'm attending Stanford's NLP class.

Comment: Does this SO question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361758/difference-between-javabean-and-ejb

Comment: One is singular and the other is plural? Really, without any more context this question is not answerable.

Comment: See the title of the question.  I think he's asking what the difference is between "Javabean" (one word) and "Java bean" (two words).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

People tend to casually refer to Java classes as "Java beans" in conversations and articles.

When written as one word, however, "JavaBeans" are classes conforming to a particular convention. A JavaBean is a Java Object that is serializable, has a nullary constructor, and allows access to properties using getter and setter methods.  See [Wikipedia's article on JavaBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) for more information.

It's also important to note the [difference between a Javabean and an EJB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361758/difference-between-javabean-and-ejb).